# Why do black pixels appear when rendering image with alpha?

Tags: rendering, transparency

I have a png image with alpha with transparen areas. I am rendering it with transparent backgraund adding red background in compositing, but black pixels appear on edges of shape on image. How can I remove those black pixels? .
File with image used:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: yes its here https://fileup.to/5ioj/ground.zip

Comment: thanks but you first need to pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: And please upload the file with the packed image here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there instead of some external source where we have to wait before we can start the download.

Comment: thanks i packed it here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=aqNMosaY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/aqNMosaY/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Denoise* function in Blender is quite good, but it cannot do magic. You have set the *Max Samples* for *Render* to 1. This is very low. Increasing it to 2 is still very low, but gets rid of the artifacts.

[image: render samples]

Apart from that the low samples make your texture very blurry. Compare the left image at 2 samples with the one on the right at 50 samples (especially the area pointed at). And the render with 50 samples took only 0.2 seconds longer.

[image: samples comparison]

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks so much better now, very helpful information!

Comment: @Hanya And beware that although in my example 2 samples were enough to get rid of the artifacts, this is because I rendered at a size of 50% as your render settings were in the file. At 100% the texture will have a higher resolution and then there is more potential for noise/artifacts, 2 samples are not sufficient anymore. So you have to find a balance between low samples to reduce render times but enough samples to get rid of artifacts.

Comment: I always struggle when doing renders, and now knowing all you said will make me more comfortable when doing renders. I will try ro find the balance, thank you!

Comment: @Hanya Some people even consider 500 samples still low, for my renders 200 samples are sufficient most of the time. But there's other things as well in your file, for example the _Light Paths_ > _Max Bounces_ settings in the _Render Properties_. They are all set to 1 except for _Volume_ and _Transparent_. As soon as you are going to render things like glass, the _Glossy_ and _Transmission_ bounces are far too low to give good results (and then you have to increase _Total_ as well), and if you put more objects with alpha transparency in a scene, the _Transparency_ at 10 is very low, too.

Comment: Its because I was rendering animation, so I realy wanted to have as short render time as possible. (i used some youtube video to help me shorten the time)

Comment: I cannot give you a general answer. If you want to render animations quickly, you need low values. But as soon as you have glass, alpha transparency etc. it can start to look bad. But even higher values don't have to slow down render times very much - it also depends on how much complex geometry using these bounces is present in the scene. In my answer here you can see a comparison how the glossy bounces influence the look of glass for example: [Grey artifacts in glass bottle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277790/grey-artifacts-in-glass-bottle/277809#277809)

Comment: For example, my settings are like this (but I don't render animations very often): Total 64, Diffuse 4, Glossy 32, Transmission 64, Volume 1, Transparent 128. And in my answer here are other examples of how the bounces influence the look: [Why does my glass shader have this black artifact?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273230/why-does-my-glass-shader-have-this-black-artifact/273264#273264)